# two while loop using prepared statement but my inner while loop is not working

Tags: php, prepared-statement

prepared statement : i am using two while loop, but my inner while loop is not working. when i use inner while loop its showing me only one record but when i remove inner while loop i can see all the records..how can i solve it?

here is my code

```
<table width="100%"  style="background-color:#F2F2F2;border:1px solid #F2F2F2;border-radius:15px;">
<form name="form1" id="form1" method="post" action="">  
<tr>
<td align="">
<table width="100%"  style="background-color:#F2F2F2;border:1px solid #F2F2F2;border-radius:15px;">
<tr class="table-heading">
<td >&nbsp;Qty.</td>
<td >&nbsp;Writer</td>
<td >&nbsp;Status</td>
<td >&nbsp;</td>
</tr><?php  
if($stmt->prepare("select id,qty,action_flag,status,writer from tbl_order where status=? and action_flag=? and order_id=?"))
{
$action='confirm';
$status='orderprocessing';
$ordid=$_GET["ordid"];
$stmt->bind_param('sss',$status,$action,$ordid);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
$stmt->bind_result($id,$qty,$action_flag,$status,$writer);
}   
while($stmt->fetch())       // outer while loop
{
?>
<tr align="left" style="line-height:30px;font-size:12px;">
<td >&nbsp;<?php echo $qty; ?></td>
<td align="center" width="160" >
<select name="selwrt" id="selwrt" class="reginput" style="text-transform:capitalize;width:150px;height:25px;" >
<option value="">Select Writer</option>
<?php
if($stmt->prepare("select id,writer_name from tbl_writer order by writer_name"))
{   
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
$stmt->bind_result($wid,$writer_name);  
}   
while($stmt->fetch())         // inner while loop
{
?>
<option value="<?php echo $wid; ?>"<?php if($writer==$wid) echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>><?php echo $writer_name; ?></option><?php } ?>
</select>
</td>
<td align="center" width="160"  ><select name="selst" id="selst" class="reginput" style="text-transform:capitalize;width:150px;height:25px;">
<option value="">Select Status</option>
<option value="inprogress"<?php if($status=='inprogress') echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>In Progress</option>
<option value="jobdone"<?php if($status=='jobdone') echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>Job Done</option>
</select>
</td>
<td  style="vertical-align:top;" ><input type="submit" name="btnsave" id="btnsave" value="SAVE" class="btnstyle" style="padding:3px;"/>
<input type="hidden" name="pid" id="pid" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" ></td>                      
</tr><?php } ?>
<tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're replacing the initial result with the second one on the first time through the loop. Since you want to use both result sets at the same time, use separate variables for the two requests - i.e. replace `$stmt` inside the `while` loop with a different instance.

Answer (score 0):

As Mark stated, You are using the same value for both. I don't really know what data you are calling however as they the same the following occurs.

```
While (outer loop) {
  Starts with first record
While (Inner Loop) {
  Goes through all the data
}
  Goes back to the top and than realizes that all the data is completed (which was done    in the inner loop)
}
```

2 Ways to solve this. Use a different object for each while which could be fairly impracticable. (two separate methods doing the same thing)
You could also maybe use a foreach loop. This would also solve the problem in a cleaner fashion if it works.

Comment: sorry but i am little bit confuse ...can you please tell me how can use different object?

Comment: Considering your question, I'm assuming that you are using a library from somewhere and this is the code. I can't see from your code what the object '$stmt->fetch()' is or where it comes from. It would suggest that on a new line you output 'print_r($stmt->fetch());' -- see what that comes up with and than go from there

Comment: And sorry, I meant using a different object would be fairly impracticable. You would be doubling up on code. Using a foreach is lot better option. (I've edited my answer)

Comment: how should i use foreach loop ? like this foreach($stmt->fetch() as $rw)

Comment: Ya..... you could foreach($stmt->fetch() as $rw): DO SOME STUFF endforeach; --- but if it doesn't work than you have a problem. Try the print_r code from above first and post what that outputs

Comment: i have used foreach($stmt->fetch() as $rw); but its showing me lots of errors

Comment: how and where i need to use print_r ?

Comment: i have used print_r($stmt->fetch()); for first while loop and its showing me 1

Comment: Sorry, your comments didn't show and it seems as if your print_r did not post correctly. Basically we are just checking to make sure that there is a list of information which can be looped through correctly.